# Redux-typescript , how to properly type state mapped to props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have those types

```
interface UsersTokenInfoProps {
    selectedToken: String,
    loadRedisKey: Function
}
```

Those are my dispactchers and mapped states

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => state;

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        loadRedisKey: async (el) => {
            dispatch(loadRedisKey(el));
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my component

```
export const UsersTokenInfo: React.FC<UsersTokenInfoProps> = (props: UsersTokenInfoProps) => {

    React.useEffect(() => {
        getTokenInfo(props.selectedToken);
    }, [props.selectedToken])


    const getTokenInfo = id => {
        if (id != "") {
            props.loadRedisKey(id);
        }
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log("........")
        console.log(props.redisReducer.decodedRedisKey) //error redisreducer does not exist on type UsersTokenInfoProps
        console.log("........")
    }, [props.redisReducer.decodedRedisKey])

.....
```

This is my reducer

```
import { Action } from "../store/types";
import { GET_REDIS_KEY_INFO } from "../constants/actionTypes";

const defaultState = {
    decodedRedisKey: {}
}

const redisReducer = (state = defaultState, action: Action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_REDIS_KEY_INFO: {
            return {
                ...state,
                decodedRedisKey: action.payload
            }
        }
        default:
            return {
                ...state,
            };
    }
}

export default redisReducer;
```

So i dont understand how can i read the state in my reducer, because i dont understand how to type it so ts is giving errors

Comment: It would be greate if you share minimum reproducable code in TS playground. I don't understand which part of the code causes problems

Comment: @captain-yossarian I will try to upload it to a sandbox, but the error is in the comment in the third codeblock ```console.log(props.redisReducer.decodedRedisKey)``` . Apparently its missing typing in the interface, and I dont understand what kind of typing it needs

Comment: I ended up using any